# is there any time limit for the selenium to be page crash?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, selenium, aws-copilot

the main question is that is there any time limit in docker for the page to be crashed on selenium?

My main code is running correctly on the local machine but it is not running correctly on the aws services or docker machine. It downs after running in a 10 minutes

Comment: Update the question with the error you observe.

Comment: No, there is nothing like time-limit in AWS instances, explain your scenario and post the code.